# C enum different compilers

Tags: c++, c, gcc, enums, mingw

I'm building an application that needs to compile on both Windows and Linux. The application is written in C, almost everything works except the MinGW compiler refuses this

```
typedef struct somestruct{
   ...snip...
   enum {NODE, REAL} type;
};

somestruct* something;
switch (something->type){
 case NODE:
   ...stuff...;
   break;
 case REAL:
   ...otherstuff...;
   break;
}
```

It says NODE and REAL are not defined,
But if I supply a scope resolution

```
case somestruct::NODE
```

This compiles with MinGW 3.4.1, but fails to compile with gcc 4.1.2 on linux. Is this simply a compiler issue that needs to be resolved with preprocessors or is there some other explanation?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are asking about C and not C++?

Comment: It is definitely C, "something" is a pointer.

Comment: C does not have a struct scope like you use it in somestruct::NODE. you must be talking about some other language

Comment: You're right, the scope resolution operator doesn't exist in C, but this is what makes it work in MinGW. I suppose the real problem is I don't understand MinGW, or developing on the windows platform.

Comment: MinGW is both a C and a C++ compiler. If you use the :: operator and you don't get a syntax error, you are using it as a C++ compiler. This has nothing to do with Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get rid of the nesting, it should work portably:

```
typedef enum somestruct_type {
    somestruct_type_NODE, somestruct_type_REAL
} somestruct_type;
typedef struct somestruct {
   ...snip...
   somestruct_type type;
} somestruct;
```

I have seen code very similar to this be ported to a large number of C and C++ compilers.

(I'm not saying this is the only way to do it; I'm just saying that this way works).

Answer (score 6):

The app is written in "C", yet the compiler demands that you do `somestruct::NODE`, which is valid "C++", but not valid "C".

Conclusion: you are compiling this code with MinGW in C++ mode, but with all the other compilers in C mode.

Probable cause: MinGW may not treat `foo.C` and `foo.c` the same, and your files are named with a capital C suffix (which implies C++ on UNIX).

Solution: add `-xc` flag to MinGW to force plain-C compiles.